# One Stacked Bar Graph, one not - Excel

Tags: excel, graph

I'm looking for both a stacked bar graph and a non-stacked bar graph in the same chart.

[image]

The graph on the right shows all the bars that I have. I want the blue to be superimposed on the orange, but I also want the grey to show up next to the blue - without the orange. Essentially combining the two graphs on top. So the end will have two bars, with the blue bar having a shade of orange on top and the grey next to it.

Here's the data as well:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out an answer: you can alter the formatting in a particular way to make it work. Not sure exactly why this works, but anyways...

[image]

Here's the website where I got the idea from :

https://alesandrab.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/create-combination-stacked-clustered-charts-in-excel/